# f.collection_sellect - How to select distinct values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to bind Categories drop down on Posts Search page. The drop down should display only those Categories which are referred in Posts table.

Following line binds ALL Cetegories:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:cat_id_eq, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, :include_blank => 'Any') %>
```

Where as following line does NOT bind the list of unique Categories (ONLY those which are referred in Posts table, that is what i am looking for)

```
<%= f.collection_select(:cat_id_eq, Post.uniq.pluck(:vendor_id).compact.sort, :id, :name, :include_blank => 'Any') %>
```

*NOTE: Post belongs_to Category and Category has_many Posts.*

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:cat_id_eq, Category.joins(:posts).uniq, :id, :name, :include_blank => 'Any') %>
```

Comment: Exact solution (with thanks):
<%= f.collection_select(:cat_id_eq, Category.joins(:posts).uniq.sort, :id, :name, :include_blank => 'Any') %>

Comment: Glad it worked :)!  Though I am not sure why does it need a `.uniq.sort`.  `Category.joins(:posts)` by default fetches unique records, sorted on 'id'.

Comment: Without .uniq, join repeated a category in results for X times, where X = total number of posts having that cat_id. And yes, .sort can be omitted :)

Comment: Oh yes, that should be. My bad! thanks! Let me update the answer! :)

Comment: What if I want to sort the list in drop-down ?

Comment: How do you want to sort it? If its not on basis of 'id', do `Category.joins(:posts).order(:column_name).uniq` and it will return an array with categories ordered as on basis of column name